# Hot to make unique NavLink for each element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some problem. I get an array from my local Json file and put it to local state. Below, you can see where i'm using **map** to show all *models* from array *phone*. When I click to one of them It makes new link with special id (which contains in array). My *Route* in in App component, but this *NavLink* is in *Shop Component*. (you can see below)

```
const App = () => {
  return  (
    <div >
      <Header />
      <div>
        <Route path="/LogIn" render={() => <LogIn />} />
        <Route path="/Shop" render={() => <Goods />} />
        <div>
          <Route path="/CurrentIphone" render={() => <CurrentIphone />} />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

So, I don't know how to creat component *CurrentIphone* with unique parameters.
When User click to one of them, user has to see only parameters (price, model etc) which are  respond to it's **id**

```
class Iphone extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      phone: []
    }
  }

  //put domain's title to prevent circular dependency on windows
  //domain's title 'MyWebShop/'

  componentDidMount() {
    getPhone.then(({data}) => {
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
          {this.state.phone.map((p,index) => (
            <div className='model' key={index}>             
              <NavLink to={'/CurrentIphone' + p.id}>{p.body.model}</NavLink> 
            </div>))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Iphone;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your question is, or why you use a class component for IPhone. From what I understood, you need a dynamic route.

```
  <Route path="/CurrentIphone" render={() => <CurrentIphone />} />
```

should be

```
  <Route path="/CurrentIphone/:id" render={() => <CurrentIphone />} />
```

PS, passing children instead of render is the preferred way.

```
 <Route path="/CurrentIphone/:id">
        <CurrentIphone />
 </Route>
```

Also, it seems like you're missing a "/".

```
 <NavLink to={'/CurrentIphone' + p.id}>{p.body.model}</NavLink>
```

most likely needs to be

```
 <NavLink to={'/CurrentIphone' + p.id}>{p.body.model}</NavLink>
```

or using template literals

```
 <NavLink to={`/CurrentIphone/{p.id}`}>{p.body.model}</NavLink>
```

Ok, I will extend my answer a bit more.

your CurrentIphone component should look something like this.

BTW, I am assuming you are not using typescript.

```
  const CurrentIPhone = ({ match }) =>{
    // the match prop and id that we destructure from it is there because you 
    // used the Route component with the path "CurrentPhone/:id"
    const { params } = match;
    const { id } = params;

    // all this nasty match params id stuff can be avoided if you just use 
    // the new react router hooks.
    // if that was the case, you wouldn't destructure any props
    // you would just use 
    let { id } = useParams()

    const [deviceList, setDeviceList] = useState([])

    // get the list of all the devices and store it in state, as you did in 
    // the other iphone component
    useEffect(()=>{
        getPhone.then(({ data }) => {
         setDeviceList(data)
        })
      }, [])

    // take the array of all devices and the id you have from the match prop
    // and get the device by comparing the two id's
    const chosenDevice = deviceList && deviceList.filter(el=>el.id===id)

    return(
      <div>{chosenDevice && chosenDevice.name}</div>
    )
  }
```

Don't forget to import useEffect and useState from react

Comment: I have an array with object, every object has own properties.. When User click, for example on Iphone X, there's can be information only about Iphone X, the same situatuon with other models..And I don't know how to create component which shows to user these properties

Comment: you need to have the :id as part of your path. then the component you're building, CurrentPhone, should take the id from it's route and use it to fetch the correct model from the json.
I would highly advise to use the latest react-router hooks to extract the id parameter from the route

Comment: I do not quite understand how to do this. I did special Id for each Item, but what I have to make inside 'CurrentIphone'

Comment: Ok, it's clear, but i have this problem:  Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'match' as it is undefined. (I'm using Route path="/CurrentIphone/:id")

Comment: ah sorry, there is params in between.
try
 const {params} =  match;
const {id} = params; I've edited the post

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'params' of 'match' as it is undefined. And now this...

Comment: <Route
          path="/CurrentIphone/:id"
          render={({ match }) => <CurrentIphone match={match} />}
        />

Comment: In params there is only id, so I can't use othere params (price, model etc). deviceList is undefined (if i'm using debugger)

Comment: I am very grateful to you. I fixed problem and it works. (also my way is - const chosenDevice = deviceList.map(el => el.id === id ? <div>{el.name}</div> : null)

Comment: it was just a general approach, you should tailor it to your needs. I hope you understand the concept

Comment: Yes, everything is clear, very, very grateful to you. And I'm sorry, I have the last question. When I put conole.log(data) to useEffect, there are 2arrays, why it calls twice?

Comment: great question, I made a mistake which I will now amend, you will find the answer in the edited post

Comment: to explain, if you don't pass an array of dependencies [ ] it will run every time the component rerenders. if you pass it [ ], the useEffect hook will run only once, if you pass it a value, let's say [deviceList], the hook would run every time the value of deviceList changed. I'd say for most use cases you would use [ ]